# MySQL удаление данных с сохранением целостности

Tags: mysql, sql

Не могу каскадно удалить данные из таблицы.

Для удаление использую "костыль" в виде прохода по таблицам и удаление всех связанных данных с таблицей `BOOK`. 
Мне кажется это можно сделать более правильным образом.

```
#Удаление одной книги и данных связанной с нею

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

DELETE FROM `librarydb`.`autor_join_table` 
WHERE `librarydb`.`autor_join_table`.id_books = '2';

DELETE FROM `librarydb`.`genre_join_table`
WHERE `librarydb`.`genre_join_table`.id_books = '2';

DELETE FROM `librarydb`.`bbk`
WHERE `librarydb`.`bbk`.id_bbk = '2';

DELETE FROM `librarydb`.`udc`
WHERE `librarydb`.`udc`.id_udc = '2';

DELETE FROM `librarydb`.`description`
WHERE `librarydb`.`description`.id_description = '2';

DELETE FROM `librarydb`.`books`            
WHERE `librarydb`.`books`.id_books = '2';
```

До удаление
[image: До удаление]

После удаление
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База данных с некоторым количеством данных

```
CREATE DATABASE librarydb;

USE librarydb;

CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`autor` (
    `id_autor`      INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `autor_record`  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_autor`)    
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`autor` VALUES 
 (1, 'Arkady Natragovich Strugatsky')
,(2, 'Boris Natragovich Strugatsky')
,(3, 'Andrzej Sapkowski');

-- Autor join table
CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`autor_join_table` (
    `id_books`  INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_autor`  INT(11) NOT NULL     
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`autor_join_table` VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3);

CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`genre` (
    `id_genre`      INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `genre_record`  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_genre`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`genre` VALUES
 (1, 'fantasy'),
 (2, 'Science fiction');

-- Genre join table
CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`genre_join_table` (
    `id_books`  INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_genre`  INT(11) NOT NULL     
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`genre_join_table` VALUES
     (1, 1),
     (1, 2),
     (2, 1);

CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`bbk` (
    `id_bbk`        INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `bbk_record`    VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_bbk`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`bbk` VALUES
 (1, 'bbk-abc123'),
 (2, 'bbk-cba321');

CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`udc` (
    `id_udc`        INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `udc_record`    VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_udc`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`udc` VALUES
 (1, 'udc-abc123'),
 (2, 'udc-cba321');

CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`description` (
    `id_description`        INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `description_record`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_description`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`description` VALUES
 (1, 'DESCRIPTION 1: so many DESCRIPTION'),
 (2, 'DESCRIPTION 2: so many DESCRIPTION');

CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`book_binding_type` (
    `id_book_binding_type`      INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `binding_type`      TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_book_binding_type`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`book_binding_type` VALUES
 (1, 'твердый переплет'),
 (2, 'мягкая обложка'),
 (3, 'переплет из картона'),
 (4, 'интегральный переплет'),
 (5, 'суперобложка'),
 (6, 'коробка'),
 (7, 'футляр'),
 (8, 'папка'),
 (9, 'кожаный переплет'),
 (10, 'швейцарская брошюра'),
 (11, 'на винте (веер)'),
 (12, 'шелк (тканевый)');


CREATE TABLE `librarydb`.`books` (
    `id_books`                  INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name_book`                 VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT NULL,
    `number_of_pages_book`      INT DEFAULT NULL,
    `index_book_binding_type`   INT DEFAULT NULL,
    `release_date_book`         YEAR DEFAULT NULL,  
    `index_udc`                 INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `index_bbk`                 INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `index_description`         INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `isbn`                      VARCHAR(17) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_books`),
    FOREIGN KEY (index_udc) REFERENCES udc(id_udc) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (index_bbk) REFERENCES bbk(id_bbk) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (index_description) REFERENCES description(id_description) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf32;

INSERT INTO `librarydb`.`books` VALUES
(1, 'STALKER', 300, 1, 2005, 1, 1, 1, '111-1-11-111111-1'),
(2, 'WITCHER', 400, 2, 2015, 2, 2, 2, '222-1-11-111111-1');
```

Результирующей Select запрос.

```
SELECT 
    `librarydb`.`books`.id_books,
    `librarydb`.`books`.name_book,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `librarydb`.`book_binding_type`.binding_type),
    `librarydb`.`books`.index_udc,
    `librarydb`.`books`.index_bbk,
    `librarydb`.`books`.isbn,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `librarydb`.`autor`.autor_record),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `librarydb`.`genre`.genre_record),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `librarydb`.`description`.description_record)
FROM
    `librarydb`.`books`
        JOIN
    `librarydb`.`autor_join_table` ON `librarydb`.`autor_join_table`.id_books = `librarydb`.`books`.id_books
        JOIN
    `librarydb`.`autor` ON `librarydb`.`autor`.id_autor = `librarydb`.`autor_join_table`.id_autor
        JOIN
    `librarydb`.`genre_join_table` ON `librarydb`.`genre_join_table`.id_books = `librarydb`.`books`.id_books
        JOIN
    `librarydb`.`genre` ON `librarydb`.`genre`.id_genre = `librarydb`.`genre_join_table`.id_genre
        JOIN
    `librarydb`.`description` ON `librarydb`.`description`.id_description = `librarydb`.`books`.id_books
        JOIN
    `librarydb`.`book_binding_type` ON `librarydb`.`book_binding_type`.id_book_binding_type = `librarydb`.`books`.index_book_binding_type
GROUP BY `librarydb`.`books`.id_books;
```

Comment: Связи и on delete cascade - сделают это за вас. =) поиск по этому же сайту на тему внешних ключей должен вам помочь, кстати в последней вашей таблице это уже есть, нужно добавить в остальные =)

Comment: Ну вот добавил я on delete cascade  а по факту данные остались после удаления .

Comment: Я предполагал что можно удалить всё запросом вида DELETE FROM `librarydb`.`books`            
WHERE `librarydb`.`books`.id_books = '2';

Comment: @hays, что именно «всё»? и куда ты добавил `ON DELETE CASCADE`? что такое `udc` и `bbk` и какая у них связь с `books`?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков *Связи и on delete cascade* У него 9 таблиц. При связной схеме это минимум 8 внешних ключей. А мы наблюдаем только три. Так что ни хрена у него не получится, пока не приведёт схему в порядок.

Comment: @Akina, так я об этом и сказал, часть уже есть, нужно добавить остальные =)

Comment: udc(Универсальная десятичная классификация) и bbk(Библиотечно-библиографическая классификация). Это всё характеристики `book`(книги).
Дополнил вопрос относительно как к чему относится.

Comment: В идеале хотелось бы что бы при удаление строки из `librarydb.books` удалялись бы также записи из `librarydb`.`autor_join_table` , `librarydb`.`genre_join_table` , `librarydb`.`description`  которым бы соответствовал  id_books = номер строки. Т.к авторы и жанр описаны по принципу многие к многим и могут повторятся и удалять их из справочника расточительно.